# Is there a way to automatically upgrade DBeaver?

Tags: linux, installation, upgrade, dbeaver

I am trying to update **DBeaver Community Edition 7.0.3 to (currently) newest 7.1.0 edition** on **Fedora 30**. When I start DBeaver a "Version Update" window pops up with buttons as options to *Upgrade* and *Details* (manually download installation file). When I click on Upgrade it freezes window and program crashes.

Is there any way to upgrade it **AUTOMATICALLY** without loosing any setup (DB connections, themes, etc.) or package **MUST be manually replaced**?

Comment: Big fan of DBeaver but the upgrade experience is pretty awful

Answer (score 2):

In Linux installation can be simply executed by selecting latest **.deb/.rpm** file which can be loaded from [official page](https://dbeaver.io/download/) and installing it via terminal using following command:

Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo dpkg -i dbeaver-xxx.deb
```

Fedora has two options:

```
sudo dnf localinstall dbeaver-xxx.rpm
```

...and:

```
sudo rpm -i dbeaver-xxx.rpm
```

**IMPORTANT**: DBeaver **must** be shutdown while running these commands.